# How to add letters of a String in a String list in Haskell?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I'm trying to add certain letters of a `String` in a `String` list.

For example: `"Haskell" -> ['a', 's']` (only `a` and `s`)

After run I get the error message "Note in scope: `xs`". So it lacks a list(I think). I have no problems to convert a list to a new list (e.g. mirrorList), but how can I "create" a list after I get a String Input?

```html
letterList :: String -> [String]
letterList s = let x = head s in 
                     if x == 'a' || x == 's' then x:xs 
                     else letterList (tail x)
```

Comment: What is `mirrorList`?

Comment: `mirror :: [a] -> [a]
mirror [] = []
mirror (x:xs) = [x] ++ mirror xs ++ [x]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before getting to your precise question, let's fix the types. Your example `"Haskell" -> ['a', 's']` indicates that the type of this function is `String -> String`, not `String -> [String]`. Note that `String` is just a type alias for `[Char]`.

The error message means you have an expression that refers to a value `xs`, but nowhere have you defined anything named `xs`. I suspect you were going for with `x:xs` is pattern matching. The pattern goes to the left of the `=`, and that declares `x` and `xs` which you can refer to on the right side. And since the empty list can't be destructured into a head and tail, you need a separate case for it.

I'm guessing the result you're after looks something like this:

```
letterList :: String -> String
letterList []     = []
letterList (x:xs) = if x == 'a' || x == 's' then x:rest else rest
                    where rest = letterList xs
```

I assume your use of recursion here is just for practice, but for what it's worth, I would recommend writing this as

```
letterList :: String -> String
letterList = filter (`elem` "as")
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris! You helped me a lot especially with this part: `where rest = (letterList xs)` . I also tried `String -> [Char]` and it also works. `letterList x =  let s = head x in if s == 'a' || s == 's' then s:rest else letterList rest where rest = (letterList (tail x)) `

Answer (score 2):

- > Not in scope: `xs`

  That just means what it says: there is no variable called `xs` to be found, yet you attempt to use it. It's much the same error you'd also get in Java when trying to, say, call a method that's nowhere defined.
- > I have no problems to convert a list to a new list (e.g. mirrorList)

  That's something you never<sup>†</sup> need in Haskell. When you have a list you can always use it directly and in whichever way you fancy. Because of referential transparency, there can never be a difference between a value and a copy of it. And I'm not sure what you mean by “converting” here, but generally it is avoided to convert anything in Haskell: parametric polymorphism usually allows you to generate the right type right from the beginning.

Now as to “how do I create a list” – you already do it! The cons (prepend) operator `:` in `x:xs` *constructs* a new list. ...Granted, it's based on the already existing list `xs`. This is in fact the *only* way to generate a new list, because the list constructor always needs a tail to prepend elements before. If you don't want/need/have any such list, use the *empty one*, `[]`, that's always available.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Even in Haskell, you sometimes need to work with mutable data (usually arrays in the `ST` monad – mutable internally but still guaranteed referentially transpart when viewed from the outside). Within such a computation, it may be necessary to copy an array, just like it can be in procedural languages.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not express myself well. My mistake. I don't convert a list to a new list, I just mirror the same list. `mirror :: [a] -> [a]
mirror [] = []
mirror (x:xs) = [x] ++ mirror xs ++ [x]`

Comment: Aha. Note that you could simply define that as `mirror xs = xs ++ reverse xs`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says - you are using `xs` on the right hand side but do not define it before its usage (i.e. no `let` statement before, no `where` statement after, and not on the left hand side either.

### Aside from this answer

You have another problem is that you are basically implementing a filter, but the result type is a `String` not a `[String]`!

```
letterList :: String -> [String]
letterList [] = []
letterList (x:xs) = if x == 'a' || x == 's'
                      then [x]: letterList xs 
                      else letterList xs
```

- The first case prevents an error if you supply an empty `String`!
- the next line deconstructs the `String` in `head = x` and `tail = xs`, which is more readable and correct (`tail x` is wrong you try to take the end of a single letter!)
- next `[x]` transforms a single letter `Char` in a `String = [Char]`.

### More elegant/homework

```
letterList str = [[x] | x <- str, x `elem` "as"]
```

this is called list comprehension, which would be the next "homework" I will give you to think about.

or

```
letterList str = map (\x -> [x]) $ filter (`elem` "as") str
```

Which uses higher order functions (`filter` and `map`) which is the second task I'll give you.

### Edit

Of course you can also change the type signature to `String -> String` as @ChrisMartin shows - then you can omit the `[`,`]` in the `[x]` statements, and respectively omit the `map (\x -> [x])` thing.

Answer (score -2):

Seems to be a copy-paste error: try to replace the xs with (tail x) ... and then think about the emoty-list problem ... Maybe you will then replace the left Hand side too ;-)